# Streaming audio running underlock

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7

I am trying to play streaming audio under lock screen using
 `PhoneApplicationService.Current.ApplicationIdleDetectionMode = IdleDetectionMode.Disabled;`
With simple mp3 file everything works, but streaming audio (like internet radio) stops playing.
How to resolve this problem?

Update: I found the problem. I use my links like this: `mms://212.235.5.168/102fm?ext=.mp3` and that the problem changing to `mms://212.235.5.168/102fm/File.mp3` solved the problem. So all links that have query string at the end stop playing under lock.

Answer (score 0):

Because you'll need to keep the network active - which consumes power - I think you'll need to disable the UserIdleDetectionMode and you'll need to add something warning the user that your app drains power - see:

- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.phone.shell.phoneapplicationservice.useridledetectionmode(v=VS.92).aspx
- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff941090(v=VS.92).aspx

Comment: ' PhoneApplicationService.Current.UserIdleDetectionMode = IdleDetectionMode.Disabled;' not worked too

Answer (score 0):

Hi I'm also streaming live Icecast stream, and this works for me:

```
MessageBoxResult res = MessageBox.Show(Constants.MSG_LOCKED_BODY, Constants.MSG_LOCKED_TITLE, MessageBoxButton.OKCancel);

        if (res == MessageBoxResult.OK) {
            PhoneApplicationService.Current.ApplicationIdleDetectionMode = IdleDetectionMode.Disabled;
        }
```

I'm streaming via MediaElement which is Global App member, maybe you should try this...

```
<Application.Resources>
    <MediaElement
    x:Key='mediaElement' Volume='1' AutoPlay='True'/>
</Application.Resources>
```

Comment: i added MediaElement programmatically and mp3 file works fine

Comment: this is my stream: (http://217.73.28.42:8000/aligator-128.mp3) and it works when underlocked, post your stream

Comment: mms://s4bwm.castup.net/994050001-52.wmv?ct=IL&rg=KZ&aid=405&tkn=20110125080009&ts=0&cu=FBFB1F1F-4626-48D2-9526-01A066F6D17B

Comment: i found problem see my first post.

Comment: Can you help me with streaming live Icecast stream? its my next problem.

Comment: plus you'll get more help if you upvote answers as helpful and if you mark answers (even your own answers) as accepted!