# Streaming live Icecast stream

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, streaming

I am trying to create my own application to play music. I have already play some live internet stations with 'MediaElement' but some stations ( "Icecast" ) not works. I am new in .NET so have no idea where to start. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Your [last question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5164876/streaming-audio-running-underlock) includes an answer from someone who explicitly says they have this working.

I'd start by adding a comment to [that answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5164876/streaming-audio-running-underlock/5165277#5165277) asking them for details.

Answer (score 0):

we play Icecast live streams using MediaElement by simple setting Source property,
but we can't play streams which doesn't end with .mp3  Please post your problematic stream

Btw. M3u are not directly supported you have to parse it and work with mp3 link 
and it can always help viewing inside stream using http://web-sniffer.net/

Comment: I know about extetnsions so add to all links '/File.mp3' and so about M3U i just getting links from them (UrlHelper). My problem is to play stream from Icecast servers (ex: http://online-hitfm.tavrmedia.ua/HitFM)

Comment: I think we're probably dealing with same problem, but it could be realy that extension thing (adding /File.mp3 probably won't solve it) becase all .mp3 icecast worked...

Comment: Are u sure that possibly play Icecast because I checked many links and only with icecasts problem.

Comment: yes, try this: http://217.73.28.42:8000/aligator-128.mp3  it's Icecast 2.3.2 (you should compare it with yours using web sniffer) But you're right there are some problems in general...

Comment: my link is Icecast 2.3.2 too and difference is headers(Current title). I think [Mp3MediaStreamSource](http://archive.msdn.microsoft.com/ManagedMediaHelpers) will help.

Comment: I think you're dealing with wrapped trackfeed info, we had also problems with this. I didn't succeeded with Mp3MediaStreamSource, please let me know if you do (I have question on stack about it)